# Determine statistical significance between linear regression

Tags: regression, ancova, linear

I am looking at the relationship between two variables using linear regression (Ordinary least squares method) and would like to compare this relationship between different subpopulations. How can I determine if the differences between regression coefficients are significant. Is ANCOVA the appropriate analysis?

Comment: "*OLS module*" ... ? This "module" is a module of what, exactly? It's hard to understand what you're referring to there.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by adding a variable that corresponds to the subgroup and then looking at interactions between that variable and the main independent variable.

Suppose, for example, your DV is weight and your IV is height and your two populations are men and women. Then you run a regression:

weight ~ height + sex + height*sex

with sex dummy coded.